# can someone explain please how the value may get passed by the argument?

Tags: javascript, function

can someone explain please how it works?
when calling the function it logs the "some value"

```
function a(pass){
  pass("some value");
}

 a(q=>{
 console.log(q);
});
```

however if i call the function like this,i get an error "pass is not a function"

```
function a(pass){
  pass("some value");
}
console.log(a());
```

and like this,error "argument" is not defined.

```
function a(pass){
  pass("some value");
}

console.log(a(argument));
```

Comment: First: You are passing the arrow function as an argument. Second: You don't pass anything, so it can't be a function. Third: Argument is never declared.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1:

```
function a(pass){
  pass("some value");
}

 a(q=>{
 console.log(q);
});
```

In this instance you are passing `q=>{console.log(q);}`
through to the function a.  So it calls that and outputs something in the console.

Example 2:

```
function a(pass){
  pass("some value");
}
console.log(a());
```

In this case, you are passing no parameter through to function a.  So the function attempts to call an undefined parameter which by definition is not a function.

Example 3:

```
function a(pass){
  pass("some value");
}

console.log(a(argument));
```

In this case you are passing an undefined variable called `argument` to function a which results in the error message that you get.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

1: Here you have passed a **function** as an argument. The **function** performs a console.log of the value provided in function **a**.

2: Here you have provided no function. You are calling `a()`. There is no definition for `a()`. There is only a definition for `a(pass)`. You must call it with a parameter. If you do not, it is as if you called `a(undefined)`. Now a tries to do `undefined('some value')`, throwing error.

3: Here, what is argument? remove the `function a() { }` code and see you are trying to perform `a(argument)` but `argument` is not defined anywhere, and JS cannot determine what is argument.

Answer (score 0):

The function `a` in the above code is an higher order function. Because it expects another function as argument.

1. In the first example the first variable is a function so `value` will a function. So due to
   `pass("some value");` it will be called.
2. In the second example you donot pass anything to the function `a` so `pass` will be `undefined`. And when you use function calling syntax for any variable which is not a function it will throw error.
3. In the third example you are trying pass the variable `argument` to function `a`. But `argument` doesn't exist so it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a pass function because you're calling it when you call function a().

```
function a(pass){
   pass("some value");
}
console.log(a()); 


function pass(xyz){
   alert('hey');
}
```